# How to convert a pdf file into CSV file?

Tags: java, itext

I want to convert a PDF file into a CSV file.
I am using iText library for this.
The program is working fine but the output is not in desired format.
All the data is coming in first line of the csv file. The output should be exactly same as pdf file(means with line breaks).
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
Document document = new Document();
  document.open();
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Indiaops-projects\\PREMIUM_PAID_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT.pdf");
  PdfDictionary dictionary = reader.getPageN(1);
  AcroFields fileds = reader.getAcroFields();
  PRIndirectReference reference = (PRIndirectReference) 
            dictionary.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                    PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference);
                    byte[] bytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                    PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(bytes);
                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Indiaops-projects\\pdf.csv");
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                    int i=0;
                    while (tokenizer.nextToken()) {
                    if (tokenizer.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING) {
                        String value = tokenizer.getStringValue();

                        if("x-none".equals(value)){
                            String datastr =data.toString();
                            if(!"".equals(datastr)){
                                buffer.append("\""+datastr+"\",");
                                data = new  StringBuffer();
                            }
                        }else{
                               data.append(value);
                        }
                     }
                  }
            String test=buffer.toString();
            StringReader stReader = new StringReader(test);
            int t;
            while((t=stReader.read())>0)
            fos.write(t);
            document.add(new Paragraph(".."));
            document.close();
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Please add the proper tag. And please show the piece of code used to read the PDF and then generate the CSV so that we can help!

Comment: If you could share some code which shows currently how you are converting it to CSV, may help us to guide you.

Comment: What does the output look like? What do you *want* it to look like? Show us.

Comment: There is a table in pdf file. But the csv file shows data in only one line. It does not show it in tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce a line break '\n' in the buffer after each table row.

```
buffer.append("\n");
```

Comment: But how to know that there is an end of the row?

Comment: If you know how many colums there are, then you know the end of each row, you might have to count.